# Can I use java keystore with TeamCity?

Tags: ssl, teamcity, keystore

Is it possible to use java keystore with TeamCity to access services that require SSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, please refer Teamcity documentation for more information on this -  ["Using HTTPS to access TeamCity server"](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Using+HTTPS+to+access+TeamCity+server)